# Change fontsize on birthdays in genealogytree

Tags: fontsize, genealogytree

I can't make the birthdays and birth place typed in example Huge fontsize. Please help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pænere danske bogstaver
\usepackage{pslatex} % Giver pænere font
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{genealogypicture}[
    timeflow=up,
    processing=database,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    node size=6cm,   % width of nodes
    level size=7cm,              % height of nodes
    level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
    list separators hang,
  name font=\huge\bfseries,
    place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d-m-yyyy,
                             % redefine default setting for female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
      male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
    % edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
  %Marriage-notes
           label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner     sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
  ]
    %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
    sandclock{
    child[id=migkirsten,family database={marriage={1961-08-22}{Langelund}}]{
      g[id=mig]{
      male,
      name={Anders },
      birth={1937-02-17}{Biltoft}
      }
   p[id=kirsten]{
      female,
      name={Kirsten \pref{(f. Pedersen)}{}},
      birth={1941-03-14}{Oksbøl}
      }
      c[id=anne]{
          female,
          name={Anne {Sjælland}},
          birth={1962-01-17}{}
          }
          }
          }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `place text={\Huge\newline}{}`, but I have no solution for the dates :-(

Comment: Please make the example you post minimal. Why do you need `graphicx` or a particular font to illustrate this issue, for example?

Comment: I don't think you can change the formatting only of birth dates without specifying a custom database interpreter thing i.e. specifying a new format rather than `medium no marriage`. However, I don't know the package well, by any means. If you wanted all dates formatted differently, that's straightforward, I think. But you obviously must know that already as you clearly know the package pretty well.

Comment: It's all dates and Places I want to be typed in a i.e. large, but I can't figure out, which command to use. Initialy thought that fontupper was the trick, but it seems to Work here.

Comment: @ErikVindFrost: If you want **all** events to be in `\Huge` font, use `event text={\Huge}{}`

Answer (score 0):

The `place text` and `event text` keys can be used to change the format.

```
  place text={\newline\Huge}{},
  event text={\Huge}{~}{ }{},
```

which are separated in `pre` and `app` and `separator` etc. (see page 179 of the current `genealogytree` manual, for example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pænere danske bogstaver
\usepackage{pslatex} % Giver pænere font
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{genealogypicture}[
    timeflow=up,
    processing=database,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    node size=6cm,   % width of nodes
    level size=7cm,              % height of nodes
    level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
    list separators hang,
  name font=\huge\bfseries,
  place text={\newline\Huge}{},
  event text={\Huge}{~}{}{},
  date format=d-m-yyyy,
  % redefine default setting for female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
      male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
    % edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
  %Marriage-notes
           label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner     sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
  ]
    %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
    sandclock{
    child[id=migkirsten,family database={marriage={1961-08-22}{Langelund}}]{
      g[id=mig]{
      male,
      name={Anders },
      birth={1937-02-17}{Biltoft}
      }
   p[id=kirsten]{
      female,
      name={Kirsten \pref{(f. Pedersen)}{}},
      birth={1941-03-14}{Oksbøl}
      }
      c[id=anne]{
          female,
          name={Anne {Sjælland}},
          birth={1962-01-17}{}
          }
          }
          }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does large on the mariage-notes become bigger than Huge on the birth-dates?